# Side Menu in Universal Applications

Tags: xaml, listview, treeview, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I would like to create a **side menu for navigation** that contains all the sections of my application. The underlying data structure is a tree (nodes, leaves) in which nodes are groups and leaves are concrete pages in the app.

I don't know a good way to represent this tree. I used a `ListView` in which each node is another TreeView, but subitems DON'T FILL the available space in the side bar. Instead of stretching until the very right of the parent, they are "autosize" and the effect is ugly.

The problem is exactly the same as this in WPF: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2008/08/05/wpf-a-stretching-treeview.aspx

Comment: Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997766.aspx) what you are after?

Comment: Yes, that's it, but hierarchical.